# Navigation stack hits obstacles

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I am trying to run my robot with navigation stack. It is a four track differential robot as it is shown in the picture below. I am using gmapping instead of amcl so I will discover and update the map as I go along.

[image description http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/14446438781100349.png](http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/14446438781100349.png)

The problem is my robot does not avoid obstacles. As can be seen in these two videos ([video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pL8A84zbzJ0), [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvR24A4_bq4)) although the obstacle is observed by the laser, local planner is not changing the directory in a way to go around it and instead simply drives through it. The obstacle is not part of the map and i set it up in a way that it appears to the rover when it rotates to reach the way point. In other words my global planner seems to be working fine, since it does not know about the obstacle.

here is my yaml files:

cost_map common parameters

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.5, -0.45], [-0.5, -0.45], [-0.5, 0.45], [0.5, 0.45], [0.6, 0.0]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55
obstacles:
 observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor
 laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
 point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: PointCloud, topic: /my_cloud, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

local_costmap_params

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  map_type: costmap
```

global_costmap_params

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3
  static_map: true
```

base_local_planner_params

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.4

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5
  

  holonomic_robot: false

  meter_scoring: true
```

any idea how to address the problem?

Thank you very much in advance

**Edit: Here is my launch files:**

My first launch file which launches the laser scanner, my joystick node, my tf_setup node, point cloud creator out of laser scanner (This one i put to perhaps solve the problem and it didn't make any changes), and my odometry. (For some technical reasons I can communicate with the robot only in one node, so setting up the speeds from cmd_vel and also providing the odometry information are being done in rover_odom node)
**rovmap.launch**

```
<launch>
  <arg name="host" default="192.168.0.1" />
  <master auto="start"/>
  <node pkg="lms1xx" name="lms1xx" type="LMS1xx_node" output="screen">
  <param name="host" value="$(arg host)" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="joy" name="joy_node" type="joy_node" output="screen">
  </node>
  <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" name="tf_broadcaster" type="tf_broadcaster" output="screen">
  </node>
  <node pkg="donkey_rover" name="rover_odom" type="rover_odom" output="screen">
  </node>

  <!-- point cloud creator-->
  <node pkg="laserscan_to_pointcloud" name="scanToPoint" type="scanToPoint" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

My second launch file which simply launches gmapping node
**gmap.launch**

```
 <launch> 
   <node pkg="gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=scan" respawn="true" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

and finally my **move_base.launch**, note that amcl is commented since I am using gmapping. Although I tested also with amcl instead of gmapping and it was the same, not avoiding obstacles.

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <!--node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="~/map.yaml"/-->

  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <!-- include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" /-->

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="5.0" />
    <rosparam file="$(find donkey_rover_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find donkey_rover_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find donkey_rover_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find donkey_rover_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find donkey_rover_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

**Update: node_graph**
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219120/navigation-stack-hits-obstacles/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-10-15**:
It seems like you have a problem with your local costmap. The obstacle is not registered in the costmap. Are there any warnings or error on terminal? Also can you share your launch files?

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-15**:
Thank you for your comment, I get absolutely no error or warning. I put the launch file in the question as you requested. looking forward to hearing your idea

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-10-19**:
Please check using rqt_graph that your sensor data is actually being fed into the move_base node.

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-20**:
Yes, there is a problem since /scan topic is not being used by move_base according to the node_graph. But why? I put the node graph in the question.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I understand it, the problem is that your obstacles do not get inserted in the costmap.

Could it be that you need to tell the local costmap that it finds the obstacle in the 'obstacles' list from the `costmap_common_params.yaml` file. Or you could try and change the costmap_common_params.yaml` file to

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.5, -0.45], [-0.5, -0.45], [-0.5, 0.45], [0.5, 0.45], [0.6, 0.0]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: PointCloud, topic: /my_cloud, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

So basically simply get rid of the 'obstacles' list.

**Update**
Did you use the corect frame ID of the laser in the `costmap_common_params.yaml`? As far as I know the LMS1xx node publishes the LaserScan in the frame 'laser' by default, not 'base_laser'. You need to adjust the `sensor_frame` parameter if you haven't done it already. So something like this:

> ```
> inflation_radius: 0.55
> ```

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

Originally posted by [nyquist09](https://answers.ros.org/users/24686/nyquist09/) with karma: 191 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-21**:
The "obstacles:" wasn't there first. It wasn't working and I was so desperate to make it work, so I found it in an answer so I did the same. The problem is when I use gmapping instead of amcl I need to set static_map to false in global_costmap_params which makes it heavy and a bit sluggish.

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-22**:
Yes good to mention, I did it already in the main executable of lms1xx node

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As can be seen the main problem is that the scan topic is not being read by move_base. Apparently this is because I am using gmapping instead of amcl, since when I change to amcl it works OK.

In case of gmapping, thanks to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9432/navigation-stack-with-gmapping/), I finally managed to solve the problem by setting the following in the global_costmap_params.yaml:

```
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
```

However it imposes a huge computational burden on the system and the computer on board starts to run slowly. I guess there should be a better way to do that. In such a way that the global planner plans using the static map and the local planner takes care of obstacle avoidance. Any ideas?

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1